# Change value to a boolean in r

Tags: r, boolean

I have this following dataframe:

```
head(data)
      Date Avg.Join.Delay Min.Join.Dely Max.Join.Dely    ACCOUNT STB_TYPE  MARKET
1 6/5/2015        1194.25           830          2072 2067215110  IPH8010 Seattle
2 6/5/2015        1215.00           945          1755 2067215110  IPW8000 Seattle
3 6/5/2015        1666.00          1666          1666 2069370920  IPH8010 Seattle
4 6/5/2015         546.00           531           561 2069376365  IPW8000 Seattle
5 6/5/2015         648.00           648           648 3032004397  ISB7005  Denver
6 6/5/2015         589.50           589           590 3033229232  IPH8005  Denver
```

What I did so far is this (my values begin with 500):

```
quantile(data[,2], probs=0.5)
50% 
661    
for (i in 500:661)
data$Avg.Join.Delay[substr(data$Avg.Join.Delay,1,3)==i] <- '0%-50% Error'
for (i in 662:dim(data))
data$Avg.Join.Delay[substr(data$Avg.Join.Delay,1,3)==i] <- '50%-100% Error'
```

This way works (excluding a few values) so I was wondering if there is a better/correct way of doing it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mts Changing the values in Avg.Join.Delay to a `boolean` of whether 0%-50% error, or 50%-100% error

Comment: could you more clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish? Does your current code always give the desired output? I don't understand why you are looking for the `Avg.Join.Delay` that `==i`; are you trying to index the rows?

Comment: in my opinion you are messing up a couple of things. `quantile` gives you the median and not an index. Avg.Join.Delay looks numeric to me so why would you use `substr` on it and only the first three digits?

Comment: @rbatt I am planning on using `Weka` for prediction so I want to use Avg join Delay as my class. I am using `i` because I need to change all the values in a specific range so this is how I decided to do it, which doesn't look correct right now. Now that I think about it, it might be because I use `,1,3`

Comment: @mts Yes you are right. now I see that it is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data$Avg.Join.Delay.boolean <- data$Avg.Join.Delay<=median(data$Avg.Join.Delay)`

Does that accomplish what you want?

Alternatively, if you want the text you had in your question, and not actually a boolean, you could

```
value2insert <- c("51-100% Error", "0-50% Error")
logical.index <- (data$Avg.Join.Delay<=median(data$Avg.Join.Delay))+1
data$Avg.Join.Delay.boolean <- value2insert[logical.index]
```

Comment: Quick question. How would I use the same method if I'd like to split it in the 80% for example?
I tried `temp <- quantile(data[,2], probs=0.8)` and then `logical.index <- (data$Avg.Join.Delay<=temp(data$Avg.Join.Delay))+1` but it didn't work. Gave me the following error `could not find function "temp"`